# How can I show data picker in android?

Tags: android, buttonclick, datapicker

I am building an android application where user set it date.

I need is that when user click on an button an notification or dialog-box open and there the user set the data and the value that the user had select is displayed to an text-view in order like 23/feb/2014.

Comment: [see](http://androidexample.com/In_this_example_creating_a_date_picker_to_pick_day__month_year_of_date/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=89&aaid=113)

Answer (score 0):

These are the things you will need to do:

- Create custom **Dialog** or **Activity** with xml styling
- To this xml add **DatePicker** view and a **Button**
- Start an **Intent** with a **Result** that can be picked up by your MainActivity
- In the **Result** pass your parameters to the MainActivity (date and so on)
- In your MainActivity parse the data you got from the date picker dialog. To do this, use **findViewById()** method, then on the TextView use method **setText()**.

Hope it will give you a good starting point.